# Calculate a calculate column in detail table in jdeveloper

Tags: oracle, calculator, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, master-detail

How to calculate sum of calcoulated column in detail table in jdeveloper
Ex.
In employee view add  column as "calculate column type" his name is "avragesal" it calculate salary*20%

How can calculate sum "avragesal"for each department

For more explain
In  employee view

```
Dep_id.    Name.       Salary.    avragesal 
100        Jone.       1000.      200
100        XXX.        3000.      600
100        Zzz.        2000.      400
200        Ttt.        500.       100
200        Hhh.        700.       140
200        Ooo.        1200.      240
```

Iwana in department view

```
Dep_id.         Sumavragesal
100                     1200
200                      480
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hard to understand what you are asking, but I think you want the sum of the average salary  per department:

```
select dep_id, sum(avragesal)
from employee 
group by dep_id
```

The [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035) is your friend.

Comment: avragesal not real column  it calcoulated colmn in viewobject and i wanna to sum this for each  record in master table

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your EMPLOYEE view is defined similarly to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW EMPLOYEE AS
  SELECT DEP_ID,
         NAME,
         SALARY
    FROM EMPLOYEE_TBL;
```

If this is the case (or something similar to this) then to add your AVRAGESAL column you'd do something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW EMPLOYEE AS
  SELECT DEP_ID,
         NAME,
         SALARY,
         SALARY * 0.20 AS AVRAGESAL
    FROM EMPLOYEE_TBL;
```

Then to sum up EMPLOYEE.AVRAGESAL by department in the DEPARTMENT view you'd use something similar to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DEPARTMENT AS
  SELECT DEP_ID,
         SUM(AVRAGESAL) AS AVRAGESAL
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    GROUP BY DEP_ID
    ORDER BY DEP_ID
```

You may need to modify this because I don't know what your EMPLOYEE view looks like, but hopefully this gives you an idea of how to proceed.